# SQL Server: Convert varchar numbers to date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is it possible to convert a varchar numbers to date? I am fetching data from a table and I want it converted into date. Can you help me figure this out?
There is an error on the last part:

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

```
declare @year varchar(6)
declare @month varchar(2)
declare @test varchar (8)


set @year = right(left('F20160316-1000',5),4)
select @year

set @month = right(left('F20160316-1000',7),2)
select @month

set @test = @month +''+ @year
select @test

SELECT CONVERT (DATETIME, CONVERT(varchar(12),@test))
```

Anyway, the the result that I want to achieve is `MAR2016`.

Comment: Why don't you store dates if you mean dates? If you need to convert, it's indicating less good db design.

Comment: I need to insert the letter before the date for identification, that is why I didn't use datetime.

Comment: You could have stored that letter in a separate column.

Comment: Guess I have no choice, thanks sir I will do that.

Answer (score 2):

The way you are storing and converting is not good as Jarlh pointed out.You could use datetimefrom parts to get output ,in your case day is missing ,i added it..

```
  declare @year varchar(6)
  declare @month varchar(2)
  declare @day varchar (8)

  set @year = right(left('F20160316-1000',5),4)
  set @month = right(left('F20160316-1000',7),2)    
  Set @day=right(left('F20160316-1000',5),2)

  select datetimefromparts(@year,@month,@day)
```

further if your string pattern is same ,you can do this as well..

```
declare @string varchar(15)
set @string='F20160316-1000'
select convert(datetime,substring(@string,2,charindex('-',@string,1)-2)
```

**Output:**
2016-03-16 00:00:00.000

Answer (score 1):

Try like this,

```
DECLARE @year VARCHAR(6)
DECLARE @month VARCHAR(2)
DECLARE @test VARCHAR(8)

SET @year = right(left('F20160316-1000', 5), 4)
SET @month = right(left('F20160316-1000', 7), 2)
SET @test = @year + @month + '01'

SELECT UPPER(CONVERT(VARCHAR(3), DATENAME(MM, @test), 100)) + @year AS MonthYear
```